# Запрос для получения всех потомков родителя

Tags: python, django

Есть модель с иерархической ссылкой сама на себя:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, unique=False, default='')
    cat = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
```

Данные:

```
1 Parent_1       null
2 Children_1     1
3 Children_2     1
4 SubChildren_1  2
5 Parent_2       null
6 Children_3     5
```

Нужно в django получить список всех детей определенной записи. Например результатом такого запроса по id=1 должны быть id 1,2,3,4, по id=5 соответственно id 5,6

То есть нужно что-то вроде рекурсивного запроса. Как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам спросил - сам ответил.
Ставим расширение django-mptt.

```
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
```

Меняем модель:

```
class Category(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200, unique=False, default='')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    class MPTTMeta:
        level_attr = 'mptt_level'
```

Теперь для получения всех потомков, включая родителя нужно

```
thiscat = Category.objects.get(id=category_id)
category_list = thiscat.get_descendants(include_self=True)
```

В шаблонах доступен тег {% recursetree categorys %}, который рекурсивно выводит дерево categorys

Comment: всё верно, можете ещё https://github.com/piquadrat/django-treeadmin поставить, админка будет функциональней немного